# Remove the calcHistogram 6 calls per minute limit

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way to request the 6 per minute limit increase for the calcHistogram method?
This limitation doesn't currently allow for any kind of development, testing let alone a production environment
I do not see at the moment any subscription option or upgrade or request limit removal

Answer (score 0):

The Academic Knowledge API is still in preview and is subject to the transaction limitations on calcHistogram. We are in the process of adding a new tier with higher transaction limits, and these should be online in the next couple of months.